# Simple CSS issue with nav links and main page text

Tags: css, heroku, flexbox, stylesheet, nav

Can someone teach me how to keep the text in my About Me section to not run over my nav links if the screen is too small (like on mobile). If you go to my portfolio site, still in the works of course, you can see what I mean. https://portfolio-kw.herokuapp.com. I'll post my CSS below. I know the about me stuff is pretty basic, but I'm just trying to keep it simple while I develop my portfolio. I'll make it sound much better later lol. I'm also wanting to play with different background animations, but liked the look of this simple animation to start.

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300|Spartan:300,400,600&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.aboutnav {
  height: 55px;
  background: transparent;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

.menu li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  font-family: "Muli", serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .menu {
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.about-animation-area {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #eb6134, #f2873f);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.box-area {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box-area ul {
  top: 50;
  left: 50;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box-area li {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  animation: animate 30s linear infinite;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(1) {
  left: 86%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(2) {
  left: 12%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(3) {
  left: 70%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation-delay: 5.5s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(4) {
  left: 55%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 3000px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 15s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(5) {
  left: 65%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 9.8s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(6) {
  left: 15%;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  animation-delay: 3.5s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(7) {
  left: 38%;
  width: 45px;
  height: 110px;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(8) {
  left: 50%;
  width: 95px;
  height: 65px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(9) {
  left: 28%;
  width: 45px;
  height: 105px;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-duration: 12s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(10) {
  left: 19%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 135px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 7s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-800px) rotate(360deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.animation-area-text {
  font-family: "Muli";
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Can you remove absolute and translate in mobile screen otherwise use fullpagejs

Comment: Remove them how? in the @media screen selector? If so, what would I change position to and would I just set transform to none? Is that the translate your'e talking about? I just graduated coding bootcamp and it mainly focused on backend ruby on rails stuff. Barely touched on CSS. I've learned a lot of that on my own, but I still need to learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

it is mainly happening due to the **flex-wrap** property. As the screen size decreases and there is not enough space, the wrap property will wrap the links, so it's better set the wrap property to nowrap.

```
 .menu {
display: -webkit-box;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
float: right;
text-align: center;
}
```

For more on [flex-wrap](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/).

[image: mobile view]

Comment: Changing the flex-wrap doesn't seem to do anything. I set it to nowrap and it still runs into the text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with a bit updated version of your code

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300|Spartan:300,400,600&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #eb6134, #f2873f);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}

.aboutnav {
  height: 55px;
  background: transparent;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

.menu li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  font-family: "Muli", serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .menu {
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu li {
    padding: 5px 0px;
  }
  .menu li a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .animation-area-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    transform: none !important;
    color: white !important;
    padding: 10% !important;
  }
}

.about-animation-area {
}

.box-area {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box-area ul {
  top: 50;
  left: 50;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box-area li {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  animation: animate 30s linear infinite;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(1) {
  left: 86%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(2) {
  left: 12%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(3) {
  left: 70%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation-delay: 5.5s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(4) {
  left: 55%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 3000px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 15s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(5) {
  left: 65%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 9.8s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(6) {
  left: 15%;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  animation-delay: 3.5s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(7) {
  left: 38%;
  width: 45px;
  height: 110px;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(8) {
  left: 50%;
  width: 95px;
  height: 65px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(9) {
  left: 28%;
  width: 45px;
  height: 105px;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-duration: 12s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(10) {
  left: 19%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 135px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 7s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-800px) rotate(360deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.animation-area-text {
  font-family: "Muli";
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Kyle Williamson</title>
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token">
  <meta name="csrf-token"
    content="ZNcsatemMEgKW5ckpHur1jbYUoFaTvZTH6HJM4P+TXsvY8hrF3p0x+pbC5D/x3drnQs150Or5/Vdf/dqnNcHRA==">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all"
    href="/assets/application-c111a4191915f76ef50e14eedf2f8b59b029f6c825026c9959ef938fbf4b36d9.css"
    data-turbolinks-track="reload">
  <script src="/assets/application-2fe6185b86bcc188be41be2247b8672f5a57c6a539d20a93e86c7e5f54df593d.js"
    data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
</head>

<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
  <div class="about-animation-area">

    <div class="aboutnav">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="/projects">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="/contacts">Contact me</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="animation-area-text">
      <h1>About Me</h1>
      <p>Hello. My name is Kyle and I'm a Web Developer.
        I graduated the University of Denver's Coding Bootcamp on February 10th, 2020
        and received my certificate. This course's main subject was the Ruby language and
        Ruby on Rails. Throughout the course, I was walked through building multiple small
        web applications using Rails along with HTML and CSS of course. Then eventually some Javascript
        and Jquery. My focus now is to continue growing my skills as a Web Developer and learn more
        in the ever-evolving world of programming.
    
        Currently continuing to gain knowlege in JavaScript for front end. Then I plan to learn
        Node.js as well as React.</p>
    
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul class="box-area">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So when I run the code snippet here, the links and about me text stay separate, but when I run it locally, it still has the same issue. Running it here as well as localhosst, the boxes come up from the navbar. I want them to come up from the bottom still. I'm not sure what changes that in your code update.

Comment: Why don't you share the code via any free tool like codepen. let me help you on this. once you have the solution you can remove the code from codepen

Comment: Hopefully I did this right. I'm not seeing where I can share this, so I"ll just post the link to the code and the view on codepen. https://codepen.io/Spartan-626/pen/PoqaVEy

Comment: I have an updated version of your code here https://codepen.io/ponsakthianand/pen/jOPKjJw , If you still have an issue please do let me with the screenshot